# Why is radiation for an ultrarelativistic charge zero on axis?

Tags: special-relativity, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

I attribute it to the fact that for an ultrarelativistic charge the field is contracted and essentially there are only fields in the transverse direction and nothing longitudinally (wrt the charges velocity). Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems to be a case of [aberration of light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberration_of_light)

Comment: This is related to relativistic beaming, namely that in the frame of the relativistic particle the environment is observed as if a ray at $\theta=\pi/2$ turns into one at $\theta' \approx 1/\gamma$. Also, the direction of radiation is near parallel to the velocity of the charge.

Comment: Your subject line asks about radiation, but the body of the question seems to be about field lines. They are quite different. Field lines essentially Lorentz contract (meaning the field becomes stronger in the transverse direction and weaker in the longitudinal direction), but radiation is focused forward (the "beaming" effect).

Answer (score 1):

The best analogy I can come up with is that an electromagnetic wave, which moves at the speed of light, only has fields that are transverse to the direction of motion.  The same "mechanism" could be working in your case.

Answer (score 1):

An analogy (possibly from Griffiths' textbook): imagine you're out in desert. Many miles away you see a truck moving on the highway. In which case is it easier to judge its speed: if it's moving radially towards or away from you, so that you have only its change in apparent size to go on, or if it's moving laterally across your line of vision?